# Need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, code-splitting, react-loadable

I am going to implement code splitting with server side rendering. For that i am using react-loadable.

But, i am getting following error while using import.

I show other posts but, nothing work for me.

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | var Content = (0, _reactLoadable.default)({
>   |   loader: function loader() {
>       return import('./components/Content');
>   |   },

My code looks like:

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const Content = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./components/Content'),
  loading: Loading
});
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "acorn-dynamic-import": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-config": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "cypress": "^3.1.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^7.2.5",
    "jest": "^24.0.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^2.0.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.26.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "react-loadable/babel",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
  }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
return {
        context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
        entry: './index.js',
        mode: isProduction ? "production" : "development",
        devtool: isProduction ? "none" : "source-map",

        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'] 
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff|png|jpg)$/,
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: "[path][name].[ext]?[hash]"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
                }
            ]
        },

        optimization: isProduction ? {
            minimizer: [
              new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: true
              }),
              new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
            ]
          } : {},

        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
            historyApiFallback: true,
        },

        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
            publicPath: "/",
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you provide your `webpack` config?

Comment: @ReasonX7 I edited my question.

Comment: `import()` is not supported on Node.js yet

Comment: I can see you've installed `@babel/preset-env` & `@babel/preset-react` presets, but they're not used in your config. Try to add:
`{ options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'] } }`

Comment: Did you see base usage example for `babel-loader`? https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#usage

Comment: @pete NodeJS version is definitely not a problem in this case, since it is used only to run webpack build, not the actual application, where `import()` gets called.

Comment: @ReasonX7 sorry for late reply but, no luck. Check my edited webpack

Comment: @ketan Sorry, I didn't notice that you specified `babel` config in the `package.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I've googled for `react loadable babel 7` and what I found is this pull request, which is still open: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable/pull/151.
Most likely the library doesn't have active support at the moment.

The good news, is that you use `React v16.7` that already supports lazy loading. Checkout docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy. It doesn't require any additional `babel` presets or plugins - you should be find to use it with settings that you already have.

Comment: But it not support with server side rendering right? 
`React.lazy and Suspense is not yet available for server-side rendering.`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't support server render yet. If you really need server side render you can search for another library to do that, like `react-universal-component` or downgrade `babel` to version 6 in order to run `react-loadable`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help